# PHP mysqli_fetch_array() error

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I am getting a mysqli_fetch_array() error when trying to execute an sql statement in one of my php forms. 
What it is doing is searching the database for the users email and returning a result. I can execute the SQL statement through dbforge and it works, however will not run when it is initiated via the web application..

Code:

```
<?php

// Start session
session_start();

// Include required functions file
require_once('includes/functions.inc.php');
require_once('includes/config.inc.php');

if (isset($_POST['email'])){
$email   =   $_POST['email'];
} else $email ="";
var_dump($email);
// Connect to database

$mysqli = @new mysqli(DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT 
  checkin.user, 
  SUM(checkin.points) AS point_total, 
  satellite_members.f_name, 
  satellite_members.l_name, 
  satellite_members.email 

  FROM checkin 

  INNER JOIN satellite_members 

  ON satellite_members.email = checkin.user
  WHERE checkin.user = $email");


?>
```

HTML elements here:

```
    <form action="" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Email Address">Email Address</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" style="width:60%; display:inline;" required>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </form>




                <div class="table-responsive" style="width:100%; ">
                   <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered" >
                       <tr class="bg-cotu">
                           <th style="width:45%;" class="text-center">Member name</th>
                           <th style="width:20%;" class="text-center">Point Total</th>
                       </tr>


<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['f_name']." ".$row['l_name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['point_total'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
?>
 </table>
                </div>
```

Comment: you mix the mysql_* and the mysqli_* API. Use only mysqli.

Comment: ^--< Yeah.... exactly. This isn't *gin & tonic*, although some like to mix those ;)

Comment: Doesn't make a difference. Took it out and doesn't pose a solution

Comment: Took it out and then what? This `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email'])` should be `mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['email'])` and quoting `$email` - Use [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) which would've signaled those errors.

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Do not manually escape and inject strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT 
  checkin.user, 
  SUM(checkin.points) AS point_total, 
  satellite_members.f_name, 
  satellite_members.l_name, 
  satellite_members.email 

  FROM checkin 

  INNER JOIN satellite_members 

  ON satellite_members.email = checkin.user
  WHERE checkin.user = '$email'") or die(mysqli_error());
```

And this needs to be

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't quoted your `$email` value. The `real_escape` function does **NOT** do that for you.

```
WHERE checkin.user = '$email'");
                     ^------^---- you still need these
```

If you'd bothered to put in any kind of error handling on your query, you'd have been informed of this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query) or die(mysqli_error());
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Never ever assume a query will always succeed. Even if your SQL is syntactically perfect there's literally an infinite number of OTHER reasons for it to fail. Always assume failure, check for it, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

It's like "I don't need to wear my seatbelt. I don't drive into trees so I'll be fine". I'm sure that'll be a comforting thought for your relatives after your corpse is scraped off the hood of the drunk's driver's car.

Comment: *"I'm sure that'll be a comforting thought for your relatives after your corpse is scraped off the hood of the drunk's driver's car."* - The body count around here are real; not virtual.

Comment: Switching to placeholder values would make quoting irrelevant.